# Website's css and js files are blocked by workplace filters

Tags: html, css, filter, proxies

I recently developed a new website as a freelance project for a small marketing & design company. Everything seems to work great, except for one issue: during testing, we have discovered that a few people behind various work filter proxies are getting the unstyled version. The CSS (and possibly a few JS) files appear to be the only ones blocked. The website itself is not blocked.

I have tried a few things to fix this. First, I validated that the CSS code was all correct using a validator. I also tried referencing the file directly on the server, with the www included in the file path (instead of a relative link). I also removed several comments within the css (one of which used the word 'explicit' in an innocuous way).

The latter action seemed to resolve the issue for some people, but there is still one person who cannot see the styled version of the site no matter what we have tried. She has been cleaning her cache each time. I have also tried renaming the file and referencing the new version for each step to make sure that it wasn't an issue with her work filter caching the file on their end. Still no luck.

I have done a lot of searches online but could find virtually no helpful information to fix the problem besides what I tried above.

I know that work filters are tricky, but it seems frustrating and strange that only the CSS would be blocked. Additionally, my client may have clients of their own who have work filters in place - we need to make sure that the site isn't a mess for those folks.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

**Edited to add an update**: I just tried moving the styles within the page and now the styles show up... but the interesting thing (which was true before but somehow hadn't occurred to me) is that NONE of the images show up, not even ones that aren't specified in the stylesheet, but rather directly in the page. So I'm still not sure what to try next.

Comment: You could minify and then inline everything.

Comment: Do you have any rude comments or class names in the css containing words that may get blocked. xxx for example

Comment: +1 for inlining, at least as a test. For personal filters (Norton Internet Security and alike), I used to avoid names like spacer(.gif), `*ad*.ext`, 1x1 images but now for proxy? Cache: she shouldn't have to clear the cache of her browser, you should instead  completely change the name of ressources while you're testing the site (and not style.css?v=12 but e5da41236.css)

Comment: Please provide a link to the website.

Comment: @BillyMoat That is normally discouraged, as it won't be useful for future viewers, and OP probably doesn't want to let the world know about the website.

Comment: @arxanas - fair enough, but in this case it sure would be useful to be able to see the site in question.

Comment: @BillyMoat I'm not sure my client would appreciate me sharing the link.

Comment: @DaveHogan I double and triple checked the css file and none of the comments or class names I seemed like they might trigger a filter.

Comment: @arxanas Thanks for the idea... I'm attempting an internal stylesheet as a test. Just gotta wait for my test user to respond.

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations no spacer.gif or 1x1 images. I was having her clear the cache at first but later switched to renaming the stylesheet with still no change.